# Netplan source route through script

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 but now when installing new ones or upgrading servers to 18.04, netplan has shown up.

The machines work with DHCP and I currently have a couple of network scripts that runs on ifup to set routing policies on multiple intefaces servers and on dhclient exit to automatically set the host name.

How can I do that with Netplan? I have read about setting static source routing but I want it to be dynamically done from DHCP.

And for dhclient exit, do I have to use `systemd-networkd`?

Find below the scripts.

`/etc/network/if-up.d/source-route`

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$METHOD" = loopback ]; then
    exit 0
elif [ "$METHOD" = static ] || [ "$METHOD" = dhcp ]; then
    IF_ADDRESS_IPv4="$(ip address show $IFACE | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 1)"
    IF_GATEWAY_IPv4="$(echo "$IF_ADDRESS_IPv4" | cut -d. -f1-3).1"

    ip route flush table "T$IFACE"
    ip route add default via "$IF_GATEWAY_IPv4" dev "$IFACE" table "T$IFACE"
    ip rule add from "$IF_ADDRESS_IPv4" lookup "T$IFACE"
fi
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/set-fqdn-hostname`

```
#!/bin/sh

# dhclient change hostname script for Ubuntu
# /etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/set-fqdn-hostname
# logs to syslog
        logger --id=$$ -t dhclient-tlmat "set-fqdn-hostname: BEGIN"
logger --id=$$ -t dhclient-tlmat "set-fqdn-hostname: reason $reason"
if [ $reason = "RENEW" ] || [ $reason = "REBOOT" ] || [ $reason = "REBIND" ] || [ $reason = "BOUND" ]; then
    echo $new_host_name > /etc/hostname
    logger --id=$$ -t dhclient-tlmat "set-fqdn-hostname: hostname $new_host_name.$new_domain_name"
    hostname $new_host_name.$new_domain_name
fi
logger --id=$$ -t dhclient-tlmat "set-fqdn-hostname: END"
```

Comment: My understanding from recent server work is that Netplan does not currently support pre- or post- scripts. I think your best bet would be to revert to networkd, or to create a dhcp/dns/router server that will provide the routes to your client (which was my chosen solution).

Answer (score 0):

To run scripts after a network interface is brought up by networkd, you can add them to the /usr/lib/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d directory.